# Concatenate href value and jquery result in href of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code present in my application :

```
<input id="input" value="Testing" />

<a  href="/captures/getTranslation/?TB_iframe=true&amp;modal=true&amp;height=380&amp;width=670&amp;" name="Signup" id="signuplink" title="Post" > Test </a>
```

I am posting some data to one page, i am getting all the attached parameter in my result page.

Here i want to know how do i pass text value with href of anchor tag.

I tried something like this, but it's  not working :

```
<a  href="/captures/getTranslation/?TB_iframe=true&amp;modal=true&amp;height=380&amp;width=670&amp;textBoxValue=$('#input').val();" name="Signup" id="signuplink" title="Post" > Test </a>
```

I have used overlay on onclick of anchor tag, if i add function over there then overlay wont come, due to that i m skipping function call on any events.

I am using jquery library also. But in result page i am not getting textBoxValue parameter.

Please suggest me guys, how to append parameter(input box value) in href attribute of achor tag using jquery

Thanks

-Pravin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the a to a button, or span and adding an onclick event, you can then redirect the users where ever you want with values from any element.

something like this:

```
<a  onclick="javascript:GoToUrl();"> Test </a>


<script type="javascript">

function GoToUrl()
{
var url = "/captures/getTranslation/?TB_iframe=true&amp;modal=true&amp;height=380&amp;width=670&amp;" + textBoxValue=$('#input').val();

window.location.href = url;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur quick reply. I have used overlay on click of anchor tag.  If i use above function, then data will post properly, but i dont get overlay. Here i want to append value directly which i mentioned prob statement ( in href attribute using jquery ).

Comment: When you say overlay, do you mean the tooltip with the URL in it?

Comment: not james ...i am displaying small window having further procedure like login overlay ( currently available on twitter,i.e. login overlay, same thng will be der in my app )

Comment: Ok, I must be missing something here, but why not just use CSS to show and hide the overlay? as the twitter login window is only a relatively place div?

Comment: yup...m thinking sm...let's c...thanks James ur info helps me lot